# Is it possible to assert if a function is an empty function in jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a generic input component like this:

```
class GenericInputComponent extends React.Component {
   constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange (evt) {
    this.props.onChange(evt);
  }

  render () {
    return (<Something />)
  }
}

GenericComponent.defaultProps = {
  onChange: () => {}
}
```

For this component one of my tests is testing if component is using the default props:

```
it('should use default props', function () {
   delete props.onChange // Before this the onChange was jest.fn()

   rendered.unmount()

   rendered = shallow(<Input {...props} />)

   let onChange = () => {}

   expect(rendered.instance().props.onChange).toEqual(onChange)
   expect(rendered.instance().props.onChange).toBeInstanceOf(Function)  
})
```

The test fails on the following line:

```
expect(rendered.instance().props.onChange).toEqual(onChange)
```

and gives this error:

```
Expected value to equal:
      [Function onChange]
    Received:
      [Function onChange]

    Difference:

    Compared values have no visual difference.
```

From what I see it should be passing but it is not. Why? And is it possible to assert if the function that's being used is an empty function?

Moreover, if I try to spy on the function like this:

```
let onChangeSpy = jest.spyOn(rendered.instance().props, 'onChange')
```

I get this error:

```
`TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'onChange' of object '[object Object]'`
```

FYI, I am using `shallow` rendering for the test.

So is it possible to assert on an empty function? Also, this is the only thing keeping `coverage` from having a 100% coverage unfortunately.

Comment: 1. 100% test coverage isn't necessarily a valuable thing to aim for. 2. If you're testing that the default props are the default props that seems like testing the framework, not your code. 3. What's the actual *behaviour* that you're trying to prove out?

Comment: 1. Absolutely agree but since this has been set by team, I can't really change the coverage unfortunately. 
3. I just want to test if the default props get used when `onChange` prop is not being passed.

Comment: But the default is a no-op. It's pointless to test that nothing happens.

Comment: One more thing I forgot to add, it is a generic input component. My reason to use a default `onChange` prop is add one in case it's not provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected because a function is an object, and objects are compared by references in JavaScript:

```
(() => {}) !== (() => {})
```

The method could be tested if it's empty by asserting `onChange.toString()`. But what should be tested here is that `onChange` is not just some empty function but a prop that was set by default. I.e. it should be:

```
expect(rendered.instance().props.onChange).toBe(GenericInputComponent.defaultProps.onChange)
```

The function can be optionally tested if it's empty:

```
expect(GenericInputComponent.defaultProps.onChange).toBeInstanceOf(Function);
expect(GenericInputComponent.defaultProps.onChange.toString().match(/\{(.*)}$/)[1])).toMatch(/^\s*$/);
```

Answer (score 0):

The two onChange variables have the same name, but are references to different functions, causing the equality check to fail. You'll need to export the default `onChange` function from your component and import that in your test to perform the assertion.

**GenericComponent.js**

```
class GenericComponent extends React.Component {
   constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange (evt) {
    this.props.onChange(evt);
  }

  render () {
    return (<Something />)
  }
}

export const onChange = () => {}

GenericComponent.defaultProps = {
  onChange
}
```

**GenericComponent.test.js**

```
import {onChange} from '../GenericComponent.js';

it('should use default props', function () {
   delete props.onChange // Before this the onChange was jest.fn()

   rendered.unmount()

   rendered = shallow(<Input {...props} />)

   expect(rendered.instance().props.onChange).toEqual(onChange)
   expect(rendered.instance().props.onChange).toBeInstanceOf(Function)  
})
```

I agree this probably isn't important to test, but just wanted to illustrate reference equality.

Comment: Since this is a generic input component, my purpose of providing `onChange` was to have a `onChange` in case it is not passed by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Jest is not able to verify the empty function because anonymous function is always created with new reference. One way to maintain the constant reference is by extracting that in another file let's say `function-utils.js`.

**function-utils.js**

```
export const emptyFunction = () => {};
```

**GenericComponent.js**

```
GenericComponent.defaultProps = {
  onChange: emptyFunction
}
```

**GenericComponent.test.js**

```
expect(GenericInputComponent.defaultProps.onChange).toEqual(emptyFunction);
```